# Showing that $\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)~dx=1 $ for odd $n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to show that $$ \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)~dx=1 $$ for odd $n,$ where

$f_n(x)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\ln^n(x)}\bigg).$ Since the integral yields $-f_n(x)$ do I just have to do $$\lim_{x\to1}-f_n(x)=1$$ to get the answer?

Comment: You need both endpoints: $$\lim_{a\to 0} \lim_{b\to 1} (f_n(b)-f_n(a)) = \lim_{a\to 0}\lim_{b\to 1}\left(e^{\ln(b)^{-n}} - e^{\ln(a)^{-n}}\right).$$

Comment: $$\int_0^1 f_n'(x)\,dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\lim_{t\to 1^-}(f_n(t)-f_n(\varepsilon))$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute $\ln x = t$. That reduces the integration to $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{d}{dt}f_n(t)\frac{dt}{dx}e^tdt$

$\Rightarrow I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^{t^{-n}}\frac{-n}{t^{n+1}}e^{-t}e^tdt$.

Substitute $t^{-n}=z$ and you have your answer.